# getting this error error TS1005: ';' expected

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

i am working on angular 6 and i am facing this error.

```
    src/app/config/config-abc-details.component.ts(296,28): error TS1005: ';' expected.

    src/app/config/config-abc-details.component.ts(627,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

    src/app/config/config-abc-details.component.ts(430,1): error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
```

Here is the version details

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
}
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.5",
     "typescript": "^2.7.2"
}
```

when i update the typescript to "typescript": "^2.8.0" i get this error 
**ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=2.7.2 and <2.8.0 but 2.9.2 was found instead**

Please help me with this issue

Comment: First of all, remove the last comma in the dependencies list in @angular/router because It might throw some error.
If you read the error you will see that the problem is in config-abc-details.component.ts. Could you please share this component code?

Comment: All the error are in "src/app/config/config-abc-details.component.ts", share the code of this file